# Is it possible to reuse a OTP Token with another security provider?

Tags: multi-factor

My bank issued a new security device replacing the [Go 3 Security Token manufactured by Vasco](https://www.vasco.com/Images/DP%20GO3%20-%20DS201007-v1.pdf) and I would like to know if it could be used with my Google multifactor security or with LastPass as a YubiKey substitute.

Inside the enclosure, the circuit board seems to have some sort of test/debugging port but it doesn't look anything like JTAG or any other interface that I am familiar with.

Electronic issues aside, I just need to know if it is at all possible to "port this hardware" from my bank issued security device and use it with other applications. In the end, my intention is still to use this device as it is which is to provide the intended information security.

Comment: Such device need to share a secret key with a central authentication server (the port you mention is most probably used for this initial synchronization). This secret key is then used to generate unique One-Time-Passwords over time. This key having already been synchronized with your bank's authentication server, you cannot use it for any other purpose. Would you buy yourself another central authentication to this same company, maybe the device could reprogrammed with your new server's key, but even that is not sure.

Comment: Do not buy an authentication server. Use [privacyIDEA](http://www.privacyidea.org), which is open source and free of charge.